# MySQL: is the order of a multi-INSERT guaranteed?

Tags: mysql

I want to know if I do something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO 
    projects(name, start_date, end_date)
VALUES
    ('AI for Marketing','2019-08-01','2019-12-31'),
    ('ML for Sales','2019-05-15','2019-11-20');
```

into a table

```sql
CREATE TABLE projects(
    project_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    start_date DATE,
    end_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY(project_id)
);
```

if the `project_id` of the second entry `('ML for Sales','2019-05-15','2019-11-20')` will always be bigger (inserted after the other one) than the first? It's not about if the ids are `+1` - just `a > b`.

So when I do a `SELECT project_id, name FROM projects ORDER BY project_id` it will always be:

```
-------------------------------------
| project_id | name                 |
|-----------------------------------|
| 1          | AI for Marketing     |
| 1 + x      | ML for Sales         |
-------------------------------------
```

---

*example taken from here: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-multiple-rows/*

Comment: Yes, It never happened to me that with auto_increment he was wrong.

Comment: b will not always equal a+1 but it will always be greater than a. I'm not sure if it's 'guaranteed', but it is always the case.

Comment: @Strawberry - How can you know? We've already seen MySQL code stopping working as expected, because it was relaying on implementation details without an official guarantee. In contrary - "a+1" is guaranteed. The IDs assigned by a single insert statement are guaranteed to be sequential.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I'm not sure what you're saying. Despite its name, AI provides sequentiality, not 'incrementality'.

Comment: @Strawberry - I mean you cannot say that MySQL will **always** do X, if it's not officially documented. The second part of my comment isn't relevant. However - I meant "consecutive". The IDs assigned for a single INSERT statement have no gaps (at least by default).

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Well, that's true, but I don't think I could construct a scenario in which it would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its guaranteed that a > b.

b can never be inserted before a in at least Mysql.

Comment: Any official reference, where it's guaranteed?

Comment: yes, you can read about it here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Comment: Then please quote the relevant part(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can look up to the documentation of VALUES and AUTO_INCREMENT

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

There is no explicit mention about the order but lets assume that on any existing language, the creation of elements on an array is sequential by essence.

Comment: something official would be nice - but I couldn't find anything either